# How to set second monitor as unique if connected with xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, output

I would like to set my HDMI monitor as the unique output of my laptop when the monitor is connected. Now I am changing it manually everytime I switch on my laptop with my monitor connected, but I would like to do it automatically.

I have read that you can change resolutions and monitors using xrandr, but I have not been able to do it. With that, I would be able to write the command in the bashrc file to check if the monitor is connected and if yes, change the output. Any suggestions about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best wat I found to do that it's using the arandr tool. . The equivalent command would be:
        xrandr --output HDMI-1-3 --off --output HDMI-1-2 --primary --mode 2560x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1-1 --off --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1-2 --off --output DP-1-1 --off

Answer (score 0):

I created a script `Screens.sh` at `$HOME` that deactives the first monitor (laptop) if there is other

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --prop | grep "[^dis]connected" | cut --delimiter=" " -f1> "$HOME/currentScreens.txt"
echo "Number of active screens:" $(< "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" wc -l)
if [ $(< "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then 
   echo "You have more than one screen active"
   xrandr --output $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==2') --primary
   echo "$(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==2') is active"
   echo "I will disable the laptop one $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==1'); that is my job"
   xrandr --auto && xrandr --output $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==1') --off
   #dont turn off laptop:
   #xrandr --auto && xrandr --output $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==2') --right-of $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==1')
else
   echo "Nothing to do"
fi
```

After that I created a `screen.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=$HOME/Screens.sh
Name=Screen turn off
GenericName=Screen script
Comment=Turn off if more than 1 screen
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Script;
```

And moved it to the folder: `$HOME/.config/autostart`

Restart laptop. Note: if you write that in .bashrc as you suggested it will be called each time you open a terminal.

To make it work from any folder use something like:

```
sudo ln -s /home/username/Screens.sh /usr/bin/Screens.sh
bash Screens.sh
```